# Rhel 6 does not boot

Tags: grub, redhat-enterprise-linux

out of a sudden my rhel6 has issue when booting. It stuck at where the bottom loading bar finished loading. Dont know what you call that page as... Ive tried booting into single user mode but what can i do with it?

Comment: Do you see anything if you press Esc?

Comment: Are you able to boot in single user mode? If so, you probably can fix your OS - and if not at least you can backup your data.